# Current URL in CordovaWebView

Tags: java, cordova

Can anybody tell me how to get the current URL of CordovaWebView when using Phonegap (Cordova)?

I want to do something like this in Java when the URL changes to the one I want:

```
if(current_url_cordova_webview=="http://www.google.com"){
alert("Yes");
}else{ 
alert("No");
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response. I managed to do it myself by creating a custom Webview and checking the url in onPageFinished.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean JavaScript and not java.  **document.URL**  will get you the current URL in JS.